# SOLIDITY : The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. : -> Can't send ethers to other smart contact

Tags: solidity

Newbie to Solidity, I am trying to send ethers from one to contract to another but it shows error : **The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.**

I am confused, plz help :(

Code Explanation :

1. I used deposit() to add some ethers to "sendEther" contract.
2. Function defined in contract "receiveEther" is being used to check whether this contract received the ethers or not.

   ```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

    contract sendEther {

        function deposit() external payable {}

        function send(address payable _to) external payable {
            _to.transfer(1); 
        }

        function getBalance() public view returns(uint){

            return address(this).balance;
        }

    }

    contract receiveEther {

        function getBalance() external view returns(uint){
            return address(this).balance;
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function send(address payable _to) external payable {
      _to.transfer(msg.value); 
    }

    receive() external payable {}
```

in the second contract use the receive function to receive ether from other contract

its better to use call than to use transfer or send to transfer
ether to another smart contract, reason is call transfer enough gas
to the receiving contract to execute complex codes

using call:
(bool success,)= receivingAddress.call{value: 100}("");
require(success, "transfer failed);

Comment: No, its not working like that way.....still getting the error

Comment: @ThermalIce use the receive function  in  the receiveEther contract to receive ether :        
 receive() external payable{
  }